# Executing >1 line of Clojure code in the REPL from Emacs

Tags: emacs, clojure

I'm following the clojure tutorial [here](http://www.braveclojure.com/using-emacs-with-clojure/) and it shows me how to execute one line of clojure code in the repl by invoking C-x C-e at the end of the line. Now how would I execute more than 1 line of clojure code...for example...if I was in a clojure file with lots of code but I only wanted to execute a subset in the REPL....any way to do that?

eg.

```
...
...
(defn hello-world
 []
 (printf "Hello World")
)
(hello-world)
;; I'd like to execute the previous 5 lines with a key combination
...
...
```

```

Comment: I think you meant `C-x C-e`, which is what the tutorial uses. Also, could you clarify your code example—what are you trying to do?

Comment: The code sample defines a method hello-world and invokes it. I'll correct the C-x C-e

Answer (score 1):

The shortcut <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> executes the entire sexp your on, the top-level form.
see all shortcuts for cider [here](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider#keyboard-shortcuts)

Answer (score 1):

1. Select all the sexps you want to evaluate.
2. `M-x` `cider-eval-region`to evaluate all those statements in order.